# Calculate the NaN average number between numeric values in a dataframe column in r

Tags: r, dataframe, nan, mean

This is how my data looks like:

```
 dput(head(dataf,40))
structure(list(Time = c(20000224, 20000225, 20000226, 20000227, 
20000228, 20000229, 20000301, 20000302, 20000303, 20000304, 20000305, 
20000306, 20000307, 20000308, 20000309, 20000310, 20000311, 20000312, 
20000313, 20000314, 20000315, 20000316, 20000317, 20000318, 20000319, 
20000320, 20000321, 20000322, 20000323, 20000324, 20000325, 20000326, 
20000327, 20000328, 20000329, 20000330, 20000331, 20000401, 20000402, 
20000403), NDVI = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.562256741, 0.560792828, 0.559272321, 0.554727235, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.506596306, 0.504768168, 
0.536223787, 0.5476394, 0.520311992, 0.52862363, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to know the mean value of `NaN` between two numerical values, in a column (NDVI) of a data frame.

See the example bellow:

| Date | NDVI |
| --- | --- |
| 20000224 | NaN |
| 20000225 | NaN |
| 20000226 | NaN |
| 20000227 | NaN |
| 20000228 | NaN |
| 20000229 | NaN |
| 20000301 | NaN |
| 20000302 | NaN |
| 20000303 | NaN |
| 20000304 | NaN |
| 20000305 | NaN |
| 20000306 | NaN |
| 20000307 | NaN |
| 20000308 | 0.562256741 |
| 20000309 | 0.560792828 |
| 20000310 | 0.559272321 |
| 20000311 | 0.554727235 |
| 20000312 | NaN |
| 20000313 | NaN |
| 20000314 | NaN |
| 20000315 | NaN |
| 20000316 | NaN |
| 20000317 | NaN |
| 20000318 | NaN |
| 20000319 | 0.506596306 |
| 20000320 | 0.504768168 |
| 20000321 | 0.536223787 |
| 20000322 | 0.5476394 |
| 20000323 | 0.520311992 |
| 20000323 | 0.52862363 |

The mean value would be:

including the initial NaN's: 10 `NaN`

not including the 1st NaN's: 7 `NaN`

Note, I've put this data frame for purpose because it starts with `NaN`. The solution I pretend is either include the `NaN` at the beginning, so it will be accounted for the mean of `NaN` between values and one other solution that only starts to count the NaN after the first numeric value before the `NaN`.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: yes, a single number (average of consecutive NaN runs).

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to remark that in your example data there is a third sequence of 10 consecutive NaN, so the mean would either be  10 (13 + 7 + 10)/3 or 8.5 (7 + 10) /2... or am I mistaken? Hope my answer below is of some help

Comment: I did a smaller example with my example data just to show the two options that I pretend. First I would appreciate having the mean where the first NaN's are included and another one where they are not included. Yes, your calculations are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

dataf %>% 
  group_by(cumsum(!is.na(NDVI))) %>% 
  mutate(cnt = cumsum(is.na(NDVI))) %>% 
  filter(cnt != 0) %>% 
    summarise(consecutive_NaNs = max(cnt)) %>% 
    select(consecutive_NaNs)
```

Returns:

```
  consecutive_NaNs
             <int>
1               13
2                7
3               10
```

If you only want the mean:

```
dataf %>% 
group_by(cumsum(!is.na(NDVI))) %>% 
mutate(cnt = cumsum(is.na(NDVI))) %>% 
filter(cnt != 0) %>% 
  summarise(consecutive_NaNs = max(cnt)) %>% 
  select(consecutive_NaNs) %>% 
    summarise(mean_run_length = mean(consecutive_NaNs))
```

Returns:

```
   mean_run_length
            <dbl>
1              10
```

P.S.

If you use the solution that gives all run lengths you can decide if you want to include the initial run or not....